# AWS Amplify, AppSync, flutter, GraphQL, how to properly create and query @manyToMany

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've spent my entire Saturday trying to figure out why this isn't working

I've tried server things by now... Furthermore, I couldn't find anything online

this is what I have now:

schema GraphQL:

```
`type Organization @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: custom }]) {
  id: ID!
  organizationName: String!
  organizationDescription: String
  users: [User] @hasMany
  owner: User @hasOne
  branches: [Branch] @hasMany
}

type Branch @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: custom }]) {
  id: ID!
  branchName: String!
  branchDescription: String
  registrationNumber: String
  organization: Organization @belongsTo
  users: [User] @manyToMany(relationName: "BranchesUsers")
}

type User @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: custom }]) {
  id: ID!
  userType: UserTypeEnum!
  userStatus: UserStatusEnum!
  userEmail: String
  userPhoneNumber: String
  userFullName: String
  branches: [Branch] @manyToMany(relationName: "BranchesUsers")
  organization: Organization @belongsTo
}`
```

The code:

```
`Future<void> createAccount(Organization organization, Branch branch, User user) async {

Organization newOrganization = Organization(id: organization.id,
    organizationName: "", branches: [branch], users: [user], owner: user);

Organization? createdOrganization = await _createOrganization(newOrganization);

if(createdOrganization == null) {
  //TODO rollback
  throw ApiException("ERROR");
}


Branch newBranch =  Branch(id: branch.id, branchName: branch.branchName, organization: createdOrganization);


Branch? createdBranch = await _createBranch(newBranch);

if(createdBranch == null) {
  //TODO rollback
  throw ApiException("ERROR");
}


User newUser = User(id: user.id, userType: user.userType,
    userStatus: user.userStatus, organization: createdOrganization);

User? createdUser = await _createUser(newUser);


if(createdUser == null) {
  //TODO rollback
  throw ApiException("ERROR");
}

await _createAssociationUserBranch(createdBranch, createdUser);

}`

`Future<Organization?> _createOrganization(Organization organization) async {

  GraphQLRequest request = ModelMutations.create(organization);
  final response = await Amplify.API.mutate(request: request).response;
  final created = response.data;
  if (created == null) {
    safePrint('errors: ${response.errors}');
    Amplify.Auth.signOut();
    throw ApiException("Critical error");
  }
  return created;

}`

`Future<Branch?> _createBranch(Branch branch) async {
  GraphQLRequest request = ModelMutations.create(branch);
  final response = await Amplify.API.mutate(request: request).response;
  final created = response.data;
  if (created == null) {
  safePrint('errors: ${response.errors}');
  Amplify.Auth.signOut();
  throw ApiException("Critical error");
  }
  return created;
}`

`Future<User?> _createUser(User user) async {
  GraphQLRequest request = ModelMutations.create(user);
  final response = await Amplify.API.mutate(request: request).response;
  final created = response.data;
  if (created == null) {
  safePrint('errors: ${response.errors}');
  Amplify.Auth.signOut();
  throw ApiException("Critical error");
  }
  return created;
}`

`Future<void> _createAssociationUserBranch(Branch branch, User user) async {
  BranchesUsers branchesUsers = BranchesUsers(user: user, branch: branch);

  GraphQLRequest<BranchesUsers> branchUserRequest = ModelMutations.create(branchesUsers);

  final branchUserResponse = await Amplify.API.mutate(request: branchUserRequest).response;
  final branchUser = branchUserResponse.data;
  if (branchUser == null) {
  safePrint('errors: ${branchUserResponse.errors}');
  Amplify.Auth.signOut();
  throw ApiException("Critical error");
  }

  User updatedUser  = User(id: user.id, userType: user.userType, userStatus: user.userStatus,
  organization: user.organization, branches: [branchUser]);
  Branch updatedBranch = Branch(id: branch.id, branchName: branch.branchName,
  organization: branch.organization, users: [branchUser]);

  GraphQLRequest<User> userRequest = ModelMutations.update(updatedUser);
  GraphQLRequest<Branch> branchRequest = ModelMutations.update(updatedBranch);

  Amplify.API.mutate(request: userRequest);
  Amplify.API.mutate(request: branchRequest);

  return null;
}`
```

if for some f up luck this is right, then I have no Idea how I should query this to fetch the many-to-many relationship :/